# How do I setup FitNesse for use with struts based applications?

Tags: struts, automated-tests, integration-testing, fitnesse

I basically need to call the execute() method of the Struts action class. Is this even possible. if yes how can i load the ActionMapping, ActionForm, HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse objects for the execute call.

Loading of the Spring Config:

```
public class SpringColumnFixture extends ColumnFixture { 
    private static final ApplicationContext appContext = 
         new GenericXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"classpath:spring/*.xml"});
}
```

Test trying to execute:

```
ActionForm form = new IncidentDetailsForm(); 
ActionMapping mapping = new ActionMapping();
HttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse(); 

MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest() { 
   @Override public String getMethod() { 
       return "GET"; }
}; 

request.setAttribute("userName","****"); 
request.setParameter("userName","****"); 
forward = appContext.getBean(AppLandingAction.class).execute(mapping, form, request, response);
```

Comment: I was able to somehow put all the needed spring configuration onto the classpath and invoked the fitnesse process as a task from my existing pom. I get all the xml files loaded. I also tried creating a request, response, actionMapping and actionform(all dummy). i even set some parameters into the request, but after the call the set parameters are not available in the request. i always get a null request. Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: @ekims - Thanks for editing the question. Forgot about that feature. Can you let me know what wrong am i doing as i always get a null request and sometimes even classNotFoundException for MockHttpServletRequest, though the jar is present in the classpath.

Comment: I got the request and response parameters loaded but am unable to get my JAXRPC initialized. I always get message stating "Error Creating JAXRPC Service Interface: null". Any help is welcome. Meanwhile i will also keep my updates posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem. I had to put all websphere jars for the JAXRPC to be initialized and also changed my code to the below. This has helped me in resolving the problem.

ActionForm form = new ActionForm() {};

```
        In******Form form1 = new In******Form();
        form1.setActionType("View");

        ActionMapping mapping = new ActionMapping();
        mapping.addForwardConfig(new ActionForward("success","/action/viewCeraHome", false));
        mapping.addForwardConfig(new ActionForward("noLogin","/loginError.jsp", false));

        HttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest(){
            @Override
            public String getMethod() {
                return "GET"; 
            }

            @Override
            public HttpSession getSession(boolean create) {
                return super.getSession(true);
            }

        };

        request.setAttribute("userName","*****");
        request.setParameter("userName","*****");

        //forward = appContext.getBean(Ap*****Action.class).execute(mapping, form, request, response);
        appContext.getBean(Ap*****Action.class).execute(mapping, form, request, response);
        forward = appContext.getBean(Inc******Action.class).execute(mapping, (ActionForm)form1, request, response);
```

Now i want the experts to drop by and let me know if the standard i am using in a Fixture code is fine or if i need to follow a different approach.